# How to deal with a dynamic window using LoadRunner?

Tags: loadrunner

I have a script where there is an additional window that might or might not come every time. I have recorded in a scenario when the window will show up (more like additional security feature for the webpage). How do we deal with this dynamic window, like if this comes go and answer the questions else go to next page? The window is recorded as “web_submit_form” in the script.

In addition to this, the window asks for different questions in a random order. The answers are last words of the questions. I know we can correlate with web_reg_save_param but just wanted on how to handle the answers in a random order on the basis of the questions. Any help would be appreciated (i.e. book/website recommendation)  I am just trying to learn LR.

Thanks in advance.

..

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question you probably want to use web_reg_find function(see function reference in VuGen for details). The dialog probably pops up after you made a request and you can verify its existence using this function. Then write simple C code with an if statement to answer the dialog questions.

For the second part of your question, if I understand correctly the logic of the answers which is consistent among all the questions and it doesn't matter which question is shown. Therefore you can build a correlation using reg-ex that would answer any question regardless of the order.

Comment: Thanks Buzzy/James, 
I am writing the same comment for both Buzzy and James. 
After a long research, I found out an easy way to handle those dynamic answers. Since the answers were last words of questions, I correlated last words of the questions (it was a little complicated since those questions have different formats, reg_exp did not really help me) and replaced them in answer box. It is working fine. I also successfully created an “if statement” to handle that security question window by using web_reg_find (if web_reg_find has a text “Security”, answer the question else just skip).

Comment: I apologize but I am still having an issue with how to handle the security question part from HTML perspective.  Here is why:
I created a correlation rule using web_reg_save_param to handle security question/answer. This rune is placed before login starts because that’s where it has been called. Now, I need this correlation only if there is going to be a security questions page.  How do I handle that correlation part using if statement because if the security question window is not going to show up, my correlation will not find any parameter and will fail. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I think James can be of a better help here, I am a developer on the LoadRunner team so I know the product internals but have little knowledge in load testing.

Comment: check out the notfound=warning clause of web_reg_save_param* functions.   If you find that the correlation is satisfied then you likely have security questions to address.  Where it is not satisfied then you likely do not have questions present and having it set to warning will allow the code processing to continue.

Comment: Thanks James. The notfound=warning idea served the purpose. Though it does send a warning, I am fine with the warning. Do you think it is a good idea running a test with a warning? I had to just put a condition before the security page saying if the correlation count=>1, go execute the page else go to next step. 
Now I am trying to write page contents in a file. When I am logged in to the website I several names. These names are dynamic and need to write in file. I have done correlation counting but it’s not been written in a file. Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a slightly different tack to Buzzy.   Just as you have the visual cue when you use the pages dynamically, there is likely to be a difference in the web page when such a dynamic window pops from one which does not.   It could be as subtle as a a variable which changes from 0 to 1 on a returned page which is then processed by a javascript function to pop the window.

Record your page several times.   Examine carefully the differences and understand th source of each difference.   Once you have identified the one which causes the interrogation dialog to appear then you have the element to search for with either a web_reg_fnd or web_reg_save_param* variant.

The challenge will come if the questions are not passed back from the client but are generated with local javascript dynamically.  In such a case you may have to exercise the javascript function directly (in the case of an HTTP user) or move up the stack to one which processes JavaScript for you

Comment: Thanks Buzzy/James, 
I am writing the same comment for both Buzzy and James. 
After a long research, I found out an easy way to handle those dynamic answers. Since the answers were last words of questions, I correlated last words of the questions (it was a little complicated since those questions have different formats, reg_exp did not really help me) and replaced them in answer box. It is working fine. I also successfully created an “if statement” to handle that security question window by using web_reg_find (if web_reg_find has a text “Security”, answer the question else just skip).

Comment: I apologize but I am still having an issue with how to handle the security question part from HTML perspective.  Here is why:
I created a correlation rule using web_reg_save_param to handle security question/answer. This rune is placed before login starts because that’s where it has been called. Now, I need this correlation only if there is going to be a security questions page.  How do I handle that correlation part using if statement because if the security question window is not going to show up, my correlation will not find any parameter and will fail. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Your last paragraph makes a lot of sense. 
I think this is what exactly I need to do but not sure how to do this. I believe that questions are generated locally. I am not working in Load Runner but learning it for future use. So, this is just for my personal education. I am not looking for spoon feeding but any guidance would be very helpful.

Comment: If the questions are generated dynamically by the client they have a much bigger problem than performance testing :)